# Windows 10 not starting - black screen and letter 'Y'

Tags: boot, windows-10, black-screen-of-death

I have upgraded my laptop from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 without problems. Windows 10 has worked correctly until today.

Now my pc (Acer 5745G) don't boot: when I press the power button, after showing the ACER mark, it passes to a black screen that shows only the 'Y' letter. There isn't the cursor of the mouse. F8 and other options to go into recovery mode don't work, probably for UEFI BIOS. So, I've downloaded the Media Creation Tool from the Microsoft site, installed (in autoboot mode) it into an USB key, tried to change the boot order to use it...but still not working.

Please, help me. I need to access to my computer.

Here there is a photo:

[image: Photo]

Comment: Did some research, others have seen a similar screen with the letter J instead of Y; the common theme is that there's a problem with the hard disk's partition table or boot sector. Recovering from this condition probably isn't going to be easy; you could start with a [live CD containing TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was related to the HDD and reallocated sectors count / bad sectors. I have to change the drive.

Comment: As you appear to have asked the question, read this: http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts